# Javascript and PHP send a download request

Tags: javascript, php

I have a WebApp that has to create and download a file.

The file content and title are set through javascript, but I don't know how to make it download:

This is the JS:

```
$('#GPL_export').click(function(){
      window.location = base_url()+'service/createGPLFile/'+global_filename_download+'/'+global_file_content;
    });
```

This is the PHP:

```
public function createGPLFile($filename, $content){

    $f = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($f, $content);
    fclose($f);

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    readfile($filename);
}
```

The problem is that sending the file content through the URL (I have a URI function that takes uri strings as function parameters) doesn't work as my file content contains different symbols and they get converted to URL characters.

Comment: Have you tried to use `rawurldecode($content)`?

Comment: Have you tried using urldecode() on your file content before reading it?

Comment: Maybe `window.location = base_url()+'service/createGPLFile/'+encodeURIComponent(global_filename_download)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(global_file_content);`